# Evaluating a real integral through a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Given the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx = \pi$$

Evaluate it using the following complex intregral

$$\oint_{C(r)} \frac{1}{z^2+1} \,dz$$

where $C(r)$ is the closed semicircle in the upper half plane with endpoints $(-r,0)$ and $(r,0)$. The following hint is also provided:

$$ \frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{-1}{2i}\bigg(\frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i}\bigg)$$

and that you should show the integral along the open semicircle vanishes as $r \rightarrow \infty$

I have begun approaching the problem by breaking up $C(r)$ into $C_1$ and $C_2$ where $C_1$ is the open semicircle and $C_2$ is the line segment from $x=-r$ to $x=r$, giving us

$$ \frac{-1}{2i} \bigg(\int_{C_1}^{} \frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i} dz+\int_{C_2}^{}\frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i} dz\bigg)$$

For the $C_2$ integral, $z=x$, however, I'm unsure how to show the the $C_1$ integral vanishes as $r\rightarrow \infty$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you know the standard estimate aka ML inequality or ML estimate?

Comment: The theorem providing an upper bound for a complex integral? If so, yes!

Comment: Okay, then look what the length of $C_1$ is, and find an upper bound for $\Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{1+z^2}\Bigr\rvert$ on $C_1$. If your upper bound isn't too generous, the vanishing follows swiftly.

Comment: Well the length of $C_1$ will be $\pi\infty$, while an upper bound for $|f(z)|$ would be, using the triangle inequality, $\frac{1}{|z^2|+1}$?

Comment: Ah, you're trying to take the limit too early. For a fixed $r \in (1,+\infty)$, get an estimate for $$\biggl\lvert \int_{C_1(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1}\biggr\rvert$$ depending on $r$, and _then_ look what happens when $r\to +\infty$. Your candidate for an upper bound is in fact a lower bound, to get an upper bound for $\Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{z^2+1}\Bigr\rvert$, you need a _lower_ bound for $\lvert z^2+1\rvert$, since that is in the denominator. But the upper bound will look similar.

Comment: Ah okay, so the length of $C_1$ is $\pi*r$. And then my upper bound will be   $\frac{1}{|z^2|-1}$ where $|z|=r$, correct? Therefore $ML=\frac{\pi r}{r^2-1}=\frac{\pi}{r-\frac{1}{r}}=0$, where taking the limit results in 0.

Comment: Yes. Except that the last "$=$" isn't correct, should rather be "$\to 0$" than "$= 0$". Then it remains to evaluate $$\int_{C(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$$ for $r > 1$ with the residue theorem.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Also, we're currently in basic complex integration in my class, and won't reach residues for sometime. To complete the problem, now that we have shown that the $C_1$ integral vanishes, I was going to solve $$\frac{-1}{2i} \int_{C_2}^{} \frac{1}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{-1}{2i} \int_{x=-r}^{r} \frac{1}{x^2+1} $$ since $z=x$ on the line segment $C_2$. Does this seem like an appropriate route?

Comment: With the partial fraction decomposition, we can do with Cauchy's integral formula and Cauchy's integral theorem. Since $\frac{1}{z+i}$ is holomorphic on an open set containing $C(r)$ and the half-disk that bounds, we have $\int_{C(r)} \frac{dz}{z+i} = 0$ by the integral theorem. What is $\int_{C(r)} \frac{dz}{z-i}$ by the integral formula?

Comment: Well since $C(r)$ contains the point $+i$, then that integral would evaluate to $2\pi i$, correct?

Comment: I'm confused as why we're returning to evaluate $C(r)$ when I've broken up the problem into $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: Correct. Taking the factor $-\frac{1}{2i}$ from the partial fraction decomposition into account, we have $$\pi = \int_{C(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \int_{C_1(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} + \int_{C_2(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$$ for every $r > 1$. Now let $r\to \infty$ and use what we know about $\int_{C_1(r)} \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35722/discussion-between-jay-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

For $r>1$, take the following parametrization for $C_1$

$$\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb{C},\ \gamma(t)=re^{it}$$
Then

$$\int_{C_1}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{re^{it}}{r^2e^{2it}+1}dt$$

And since $|re^{it}|=r$ and $|r^2e^{2it}+1|\ge |r^2e^{it}|-|1|=|r^2|-1=r^2-1$
$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{re^{it}}{r^2e^{2it}+1}dt≤\frac{r\pi}{r^2-1}$$

which goes to $0$ as $r\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+2}\ \text{d}x$$

we stay in the upper half plane region.

we denote $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+1}$$

and we find the singularities:

$$z_1 = -i ~~~~~~~~~~~ z_2 = +i$$

The singularity
$$z_1 = -i$$

will be skipped because it's not in our region.

The singularity
$$z_2 = +i$$

is instead the region (we are always speaking about the upper half complex plane, this is why) and so we will calculate the residue as

$$\text{Res}(i, f(z)) = -\frac{1}{2}i$$

Thence the final sum is

$$2\pi i \sum\text{Res}(z, f(z)) = \pi$$

And so

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1}\ \text{d}x = \pi$$